# Sub functions in Python

Tags: python, function

Im writing a basic program in Python.
In the program, there is an array called abc. The array contains the following data:
birthdate and name.

Instead of using:
 abc[1]
I want to create sub function, like:
abc.name()
That will return the value of abc[1]

How can i create a function like this (with dot)? Thanks!!

Comment: post your code please

Comment: Then write a `class` or use a `dict`.

Comment: You cannot add attributes (ex functions) to built-in classes like "list". You have to write your own class

Comment: I dont want to add functions to built in functions. Just want to make function that called abc(), that have sub functions like abc.a() and abc.b() the will do different stuff...

Answer (score 1):

You will want to use a class like this:

```
class abc():

    def __init__(self, birthday, name):

        self.__birthday = birthday
        self.__name = name

    def birthday(self):
        return self.__birthday

    def name(self):
        return self.__name
```

Now just create abc

```
person = abc('5/04/1984', 'Nick Stone')
```

And get the data like so:

```
bday = person.birthday()
name = person.name()
```

Comment: Using "private" attributes and accessors for no good reason is highly unpythonic - the right way is to start with plain attributes, and eventually turn them into properties (computed attributes) if and when you have a need for it.

Answer (score 0):

As said, you can't add such 'function' to your value, it's necessary to create a class definition if you need to use .dot notation. Basic example:

```py
class abc():

    # constructor, initializing object state 
    def __init__(self,item):
        self.item=item

    # here you define name and body of your function         
    def name(self):
        # return just second item from our "item" value (string, array, list, etc.)
        return self.item[1]
```

Now, you can create object of class abc and call it's 'name function':

```
> myData=abc('123')
> myData.name()
'2'
> myData=abc(['birth','name'])
> myData.name()
'name'
```